# Problem in this variation table, drawn with Tikz (tkz-tab)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the MWE:

The problem is the vertical line, left to `g(0,5)` which is not supposed to be "cut".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit[lgt=1.5,espcl=3]{$x$ /1, $g'(x)$ / 0.6,$g$/2}{${0,5}$ ,$\frac{4}{5}$, $+\infty$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,z,+, }
        \tkzTabVar{+/ $g{\left(0,5\right)}$,-/$g\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$ ,+/  }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `deltacl`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit[lgt=1.5,espcl=3,deltacl=1]{$x$ /1, $g'(x)$ / 0.6,$g$/2}{${0,5}$ ,$\frac{4}{5}$, $+\infty$}
        \tkzTabLine{,-,z,+, }
        \tkzTabVar{+/ $g{\left(0,5\right)}$,-/$g\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$ ,+/  }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: A bit less, like `deltacl=.75`, would already be fine …